# Why Does This Udev Rule Only Run Once

Tags: virtualbox, udev

I want to set up a udev rule to run every time I plug in a USB drive that will connect that USB drive to connect to a VM in VirtualBox. The udev rule works to connect a USB drive to a running VM, but only once per boot. Someone please help me. I have the in `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-usbmount.rules`:

```
 KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/usr/bin/vbox-automount-usb"
```

And this in `/usr/bin/vbox-automount-usb`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set `lsusb -d ${ID_VENDOR}:${ID_MODEL}| sed 's/:.*//g'`
while [ ! -z "$1" ]; do
  case $1 in
       Bus) shift
       busdevice="$1"
       ;;
       Device) shift
       busdevice=${busdevice}"/$1"
       ;;
  esac
  shift
done
if [ ! -z "$busdevice" ]; then
  address=$(VBoxManage list usbhost | grep "Address:" | grep $bus device | sed -e 's/Address://' -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
  if [ ! -z "$address" ]; then
       su - guestos -c "VBoxManage controlvm guestos_0001 usbattach $address"
  fi
fi
```

EDIT: 
I can make `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-usbmount.rules` work also by changing it to:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1", RUN+="/usr/bin/vbox-automount-usb"
```

But it still only mounts a USB in VirtualBox for the first time

EDIT: 
The same thing STILL happens when using

```
su - guestos -c "VBoxManage controlvm guestos_0001 usbattach `VBoxManage list usbhost | grep "Address:" | grep $bus device | sed -e 's/Address://' -e 's/^[ \t]*//'`"
```

For `/usr/bin/vbox-automount-usb`

Comment: Uh, `NumberOfVMs=replaceme`?

Comment: Sorry sorry, that was a copy+paste error. The loop doesn't matter. Will remove it

Comment: Hiya, solved or not solved ? _(get back to me with @Cbhihe)_

Comment: @Cbhihe this was not solved yet. Not to my knowledge at lease