# Automount All USBs in Virtualbox

Tags: 14.04, usb, virtualbox, automount, udev

I want to have a way to have Ubuntu boot automatically into a VirtualBox VM. I have figured that out, however it does not automount a USB drive. I have tried using udev ([automount usb in ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186174/automount-usb-drive-in-virtualbox-via-udev-in-ubuntu-12-04) does not work and I am trying to figure out [why this udev rule only runs once](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612995/why-does-this-udev-rule-only-run-once), however I am open to any solution. I would love some help, thank you and I hope to hear back soon. I also need to configure the application do this from a command line.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Virtualbox manager, select virtual machine.

Then click on USB and create an empty filter for USB devices.

They will automount.

If I correctly understood your question.

Comment: That is what I am looking for, but I need a command line solution (sorry if I was not clear enough). I know about VBoxManage usbfilter add but IDK what command exactly to run

Comment: Not only that - but that does not work for me

Comment: Did you solve your problem?